# Leading Zero in Sign Extension in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, hex, unsigned

I read Kip IRVINE's book [*Assembly Language for x86 Processors*](http://kipirvine.com/asm/) and he wrote:

> **Copying Smaller Values to Larger Ones**
>
> Although MOV cannot directly copy data from a smaller operand to a larger one, programmers can create workarounds. Suppose count (unsigned, 16 bits) must be moved to ECX (32 bits). We can set ECX to zero and move count to CX:
>
> ```
> .data
> count WORD 1
> .code
> mov ecx,0
> mov cx,count
> ```
>
> What happens if we try the same approach with a signed integer equal to -16?
>
> ```
> .data
> signedVal SWORD -16 ; FFF0h (-16)
> .code
> mov ecx,0
> mov cx,signedVal ; ECX = 0000FFF0h (+65,520)
> ```
>
> The value in ECX (+65,520) is completely different from -16. On the other hand, if we had ﬁlled ECX ﬁrst with FFFFFFFFh and then copied signedVal to CX, the ﬁnal value would have been correct:
>
> ```
> mov ecx,0FFFFFFFFh
> mov cx,signedVal ; ECX = FFFFFFF0h (-16)
> ```

My problem is with last part. I think the first line in the code above we should have written `mov ecx,FFFFFFFFFh`, not  0FFFFFFFFh. In other words what is the leading zero?

Comment: `mov ecx, -1` should work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to tell *labels* and *numeric literals* apart most assemblers require the latter ones to **always** begin with a digit, even if it is just a non significant zero.

If you count the number of **significant**  hex digits in `0ffffffffh` you see that they are indeed eight, each one carrying four bits of information.
And 8 times 4 is 32.
Your literal `fffffffffh` is 36 bits long instead.

Simply put numbers like `dah` `a7h`, `e0h` and so on, must be written with a leading `0`.
In your mind you should get automatically rid of superfluous zeros.

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between symbols (i.e. variables) and numbers you have to start numbers with a decimal digit.

The numeric parameter to mov ecx, is always stored as 32-bit regardless of the number if digits you write in the code (as long as the final value is less than 2^32). Leading zeros are ignored.

In contrast to C/C++ numbers starting with 0 are not interpreted as octal numbers (if that is your concern). Octal numbers are startet with 0t.